# Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform with Real to Real functions

Tags: signal-processing, fft, fftw, numerical-analysis

I have a DFT (real_to_complex) output (5x8) that I want to inverse transform using r2r (real to real) functions, instead of iDFT, because the coefficients are all favorably real:

```
[0.000000]  [0.000000]  [0.000000]  [0.000000]  [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [-0.000039] [-5.228421] [1.999998]  [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [10.456858] [-0.000000] [-0.329559] [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [-6.000002] [0.494339]  [-0.000000] [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [0.000000]  [0.000000]  [0.000000]  [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [12.000002] [-2.471695] [2.402020]  [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [-31.370562]    [4.000000]  [-1.647797] [0.000000]
[0.000000]  [81.597977] [-15.685284]    [4.000000]  [0.000000]
```

The problem is with symmetry, the X-axis is fine; following the pattern of odd-symmetric DST-I 0,a,b,c,0,-c,-b,-a (we don't see the -c,-b,-a because this is "real_to_complex" output ). However, the Y-axis is not following DST pattern or the DCT-I pattern a,b,c,d,e,d,c,b. I don't see it being symmetric however, because the coefficients are real and the output is real, we should be able to calculate this with only real values.

The iDFT 8x8 output is the following:

```
 [1.694307]     [1.331561]      [0.590346]      [-1.331561]  [-2.874999]     [-1.331561]     [0.590346]     [1.331561]
 [1.331561]     [1.625000]      [1.256080]      [-0.281785]  [-2.168437]     [-1.968213]     [-0.419204]     [0.624999]
 [0.590346]     [1.580797]      [2.125001]      [1.212098]   [-0.840346]     [-2.048974]     [-1.875001]     [-0.743921]
 [-1.331561]     [1.031788]     [2.951028]      [4.125000]   [2.168437]     [-1.875002]     [-3.787904]     [-3.281786]
 [-2.874999]     [-2.168437]     [-0.840346]     [2.168437]  [4.555690]     [2.168437]      [-0.840346]     [-2.168437]
 [-1.331561]     [-3.281786]     [-3.787904]     [-1.875002] [2.168437]     [4.125000]      [2.951028]      [1.031788]
 [0.590346]     [-0.743921]     [-1.875001]     [-2.048974]  [-0.840346]     [1.212098]     [2.125001]      [1.580797]
 [1.331561]     [0.624999]      [-0.419204]     [-1.968213]  [-2.168437]     [-0.281785]     [1.256080]     [1.625000]
```

Answer (score 0):

The complex_to_real DFT assumes complex conjugate symmetry for the 8*5 matrix.

When we expand this matrix into 8-point DFTs of Columns and Rows, the columns do not meet the odd symmetry criteria [0,a,b,c,0,-c,-b,-a] and as such seek contribution from the cosine basis, producing a complex value.

However when we examine the columns in frequency space, there is somewhat an odd symmetry amongst complex values.

In Matlab we define the matrix R1 as follows:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   -0.000039   -5.228421   1.999998    0   -1.999998   5.228421    0.000039
0   10.456858   -0  -0.329559   0   0.329559    0   -10.456858
0   -6.000002   0.494339    -0  0   0   -0.494339   6.000002
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   12.000002   -2.471695   2.40202 0   -2.40202    2.471695    -12.000002
0   -31.370562  4   -1.647797   0   1.647797    -4  31.370562
0   81.597977   -15.685284  4   0   -4  15.685284   -81.597977
```

Then the colFFR2=ifft(R1 ) produces the output;

```
0.000000 + 0.000000i    8.335529 + 0.000000i    -2.361383 + 0.000000i   0.8030828 + 0.000000i   0.000000 + 0.000000i    -0.8030828 + 0.000000i  2.361383 + 0.000000i    -8.335529 + 0.000000i
0.000000 + 0.000000i    6.681977 - 3.574877i    -1.673753 + 0.6864277i  0.3180193 - 0.2243077i  0.000000 + 0.000000i    -0.3180193 + 0.2243077i 1.673753 - 0.6864277i   -6.681977 + 3.574877i
0.000000 + 0.000000i    2.614213 - 7.949751i    -0.5000000 + 0.9363536i 0.2471695 + 0.05025225i 0.000000 + 0.000000i    -0.2471695 - 0.05025225i    0.5000000 - 0.9363536i  -2.614213 + 7.949751i
0.000000 + 0.000000i    -6.681977 - 14.03173i   1.673753 + 1.686428i    -0.3180193 - 0.5538672i 0.000000 + 0.000000i    0.3180193 + 0.5538672i  -1.673753 - 1.686428i   6.681977 + 14.03173i
0.000000 + 0.000000i    -13.56396 + 0.000000i   3.361383 + 0.000000i    -1.297422 + 0.000000i   0.000000 + 0.000000i    1.297422 + 0.000000i    -3.361383 + 0.000000i   13.56396 + 0.000000i
0.000000 + 0.000000i    -6.681977 + 14.03173i   1.673753 - 1.686428i    -0.3180193 + 0.5538672i 0.000000 + 0.000000i    0.3180193 - 0.5538672i  -1.673753 + 1.686428i   6.681977 - 14.03173i
0.000000 + 0.000000i    2.614213 + 7.949751i    -0.5000000 - 0.9363536i 0.2471695 - 0.05025225i 0.000000 + 0.000000i    -0.2471695 + 0.05025225i    0.5000000 + 0.9363536i  -2.614213 - 7.949751i
0.000000 + 0.000000i    6.681977 + 3.574877i    -1.673753 - 0.6864277i  0.3180193 + 0.2243077i  0.000000 + 0.000000i    -0.3180193 - 0.2243077i 1.673753 + 0.6864277i   -6.681977 - 3.574877i
```

Finally ifft(colFFR2.', 'symmetric') provides the matching iDFT.